# Using javascript to capture values

Tags: javascript

I have a multi-page form which uses php and javascript to capture and store the various values.

The form is working well apart from one issue which has left me stumped. At the third stage of the form there is an optional extras section which works as it should when something is selected, but if nothing is selected the previous value is not carried forward to the next stage.

I'm guesing it's because I'm using a click function - so if nothing is selected it falls over. How do I get around this?

```
$('.radio2').click(function() {
            var servicecost = <?php echo json_encode($_POST['sum']); ?>;
            var sum2 = parseInt(servicecost);
            $('.radio2:checked').each(function() {
                sum2 += parseFloat($(this).closest('div').find('.values').text());
            });
            $('#sum2').html(sum2);
            $("input[name=sum3]").val(sum2);
            });
```

The servicecost is the value of the selected options on the previous page.

Comment: I think you answered your own question, right? You need to fill up a hidden somewhere for a fallback if your user never invokes the click handler. Then if there's no `sum3`, you can grab from `<input type="hidden" name="sumOriginal" value="<?php echo json_encode($_POST['sum']); ?>">` or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by hiding the Next button until an option is selected. I added a new option (No optional extras) with a value of 0 for users that don't require any and this got around the click function issue.

Answer (score 0):

Passing values extracted by script between pages can be acheived in a few ways.

1. Use HTML5 Local/Session Storage - however your pages should belong to the same domain.This requires a HTML5 enabled browser.
2. Use cookies (same domain policy again) and will not work if cookies are disabled.
3. Send the data through URL encoding.
4. POST the data to server and then send it back from server.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. As you have written the logic to print servicecost in click event, you will not be able to print the service cost from previous page. My suggestion would be,

You set the div sum2 when you arrive to the current form.
Note: Make sum2 as global so that you don't need to use POST..
 May be,
`$(document).ready( function () {
     var servicecost = <?php echo json_encode($_POST['sum']); ?>;
     var sum2 = parseInt(servicecost); 
     $('#sum2').html(sum2);
     $("input[name=sum3]").val(sum2);
});`

Comment: That worked for when I don't select anything at that stage (the value from the previous page is carried over to the next one), but now the values from this stage are not added to the running total if checked.

Comment: Make var sum2 as global so that you don't need to use POST. Comment these two lines.. var servicecost = <?php echo  json_encode($_POST['sum']); ?>;
var sum2 = parseInt(servicecost);